# Get string between two string with regex

Tags: python, regex

this regex give string between two string `"(?<='v')(.*)(?='d')"`,

but i have some problem sometime with regex,

like this ex `"   'v'string1d'd'string2'd'  "`,

if use this regex he give me this result : string1d'd'string2

i want only get the `string1` 
there any way to fix it

Comment: You can make the regex non-greedy: `"(?<='v')(.*?)(?='d')"` but it will give you the string `string1d` not `string1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexp matches are by default greedy, if you want the minimum match (laziness) this should work: `"(?<='v')(.*?)(?='d')"`

see: "Laziness Instead of Greediness" in https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html